# Bluetooth Background mode IOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, background, core-bluetooth

I was searching for my Bluetooth problem a few days but I did not find any useful solution. I would like reading advertising data more precisely manufacturing data from peripheral devices via ios application when it is in the background. In my case, the peripheral devices are Nordic nrf51822 chips and a central device is ios phone. I have successfully implemented the Bluetooth background mode and it works well on the ios device. The Event handler DiscoveredPeripheral is called when the new peripheral device is discovered. But the problem is that it is called only first-time the peripheral device becomes visible. If I turn off and on the peripheral device the DiscoverdPeripheral event is not called anymore. I know that this is ios restriction, but I do not know how can I handle this ios limitation. In the end, I would like that app in the background starts scanning for peripheral devices with specific UUID periodically, for example, every 10minutes. At this point, I would like to ask if this scenario is possible to implement in ios if so I appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Event handler DiscoveredPeripheral is called when the new peripheral device is discovered.

This isn't correct. It will only be called once per call to `scanForPeripherals`. When the device connects, you should stop scanning. When the device disconnects, which you should see as `centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)`, you can begin scanning again.

Even better, if you only want to reconnect to the same device, don't scan at all. Just call `connect` for that peripheral UUID. It will continue running while you're in the background and wake you up when the connect succeeds.

To push this further, implement [Bluetooth State Restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1962/_index.html), which will allow you to automatically reconnect even after reboots.

Comment: Thanks for reply Rob Napier. I totally understand your scenario, but I have two concerns. 1) When ios connect to the device, followed by reading characteristics, disconnecting and scanning again then I do not know what will happen. Will ios try to connect to the same device one more time or will continue with the next device.  2) If I understand correctly, the scanning can work infinitely long or I have some limit time for scanning in the background.

Comment: Scanning has nothing to do with what you've connected to before. It has no memory past the current scan. It'll discover whatever it sees first. And yes, scanning can run indefinitely. So can the call to connect. It can run for weeks without a problem.

Comment: I got a clear answer to my second question and thanks for that Rob. I would like to give a comment on my first question. Please imagine that we have five devices and IOS starts scanning and finds one of them, then it connects, reads, disconnects and start scanning again. At this moment the IOS has five available devices for discovering. In the worse case, it can happen that IOS find the same device again and again. It means that the remaining four devices the ios have never discovered. I hope that you understand my concern regarding multiple devices.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. It's your job to keep searching until you find all the devices you want. You can keep scanning while you connect if you need that (though this can impact your ability to connect reliably, particularly in noisy areas; everything you do on the antenna shares time and interferes with other things on the antenna). The fact that during one scan duplicates are removed is just a convenience feature; you can turn that off with `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey`.

Comment: Do not forget that most devices stop advertising once they're connected to. This is not guaranteed, but it's very common. Many devices also stop advertising after some period of time after booting up, or require a button to be pressed to advertise. All of this is highly device-dependent.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you. I tested a similar scenario as you mentioned a little a bit simplified version. In DiscoveredPeripheral event I call StopScanning and after that immediately scanForPeripherals. I observed that Ble works only a few hours. It is interesting that app did not call WillTerminate event handler. I do know what can be the problem but in official documentation of Apple I did not find any restriction about this. I think that the same situation happens if ios connects and disconnects to device and then starts scanning again.